# standard way to convert to short path in .net

Tags: .net, path, quotes

looking for the standard bug-proofed way to convert "long names" such as "C:\Documents and settings" to their equivalent "short names" "C:\DOCUME~1"

I need this to run an external process from withing my C# app. It fails if I feed it with paths in the "long name".

Comment: FYI I believe "short path" is referred to the "8.3 name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the external process fail even if you enclose the long file paths in quotes?  That may be a simpler method, if the external app supports it.

e.g.

```
myExternalApp "C:\Documents And Settings\myUser\SomeData.file"
```

Comment: It works. Do you have any explanation or documentation that explains what happens?

Comment: Not really.  It's just (reasonably) standard behaviour for modern apps to accept arguments with spaces if the string is delimited with quotes...

Comment: You need the quotes because the path is basically a command line option, and space is the delimiter for command line options. If you use a path with spaces in it, then the command line will be parsed into multiple options.

Definition: "Space" - the ASCII character often mistaken for the absence of a character

Answer (score 24):

If you are prepared to start calling out to Windows API functions, then GetShortPathName() and GetLongPathName() provide this functionality.

See http://csharparticles.blogspot.com/2005/07/long-and-short-file-name-conversion-in.html

```
    const int MAX_PATH = 255;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetShortPathName(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
         string path,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
         StringBuilder shortPath,
        int shortPathLength
        );

    private static string GetShortPath(string path) {
        var shortPath = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
        GetShortPathName(path, shortPath, MAX_PATH);
        return shortPath.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: +1 im just integrating an exe that only works with shortpaths (due to an internal bug)

Comment: This seems to fail (returns nothing) if you pass it a path that is greater than `MAX_PATH` to be shortened.

Comment: I think the strings should be marshalled as `LPWStr` instead of `LPTStr`.

Comment: whether LPWStr or LPTStr, this method just returns the original (long) filename for me

Answer (score 4):

The trick with GetShortPathName from WinAPI works fine, but be careful when using very long paths there.

We just had an issue when calling 7zip with paths longer than MAX_PATH. GetShortPathName wasn't working if the path was too long. Just prefix it with "\?\" and then it will do the job and return correctly shortened path.